# Flink Infer kafka topic DDL

Tags: apache-flink, flink-streaming, flink-sql

Is there any way to auto infer Kafka topic DDL in Flink without the need of manually `CREATE TABLE` query, just like in the case of spark.

Answer (score 1):

You could use Flink Catalogs to connect to metadata repositories, see https://nightlies.apache.org/flink/flink-docs-master/docs/dev/table/catalogs/

Comment: But using catalog also, we are registering it, is there any way where I only give kafka topic and format as input and flink infer it automatically and same can be used in downstream SQLs

Comment: Do you have an example on how you do this in Spark? In the end, there is always some metadata that you have to register to link components together.

Comment: my bad, thanks for suggesting catalogs